# Error in Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

When I run `rails c` I get an error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/test_case.rb:12:in `<module:ActiveSupport>': uninitialized constant Test::Unit::TestCase (NameError)
```

Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: Looks like there is an uninitialized constant in a test case. Do you have samples of the test case available?

Answer (score 0):

Add `require 'test/unit'`
at the beginning of 
`/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/test_case.rb`

Comment: I had this bug on ubuntu a while back. Check this out for more info https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ruby-activesupport-3.2/+bug/1319101